# How does the Rack::Request #params method work in regard to 'super'?

Tags: ruby, request, rack, super

```
# File 'lib/rack/request.rb', line 19

def params
  @params ||= super
end
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request#params-instance_method

I know the basics of super, but I don't know how it works here: from which parent class does it inherit #params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include a module in Ruby, it is injected into the inheritance chain.

[`Rack::Request`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request) includes `Rack::Request::Helpers` which implements [`Rack::Request::Helpers#params`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request/Helpers#params-instance_method).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know super will lookup methods in modules defined within a class.   No lessons seem to mention this.